# Blank(0kb) file saved on sd card when opening camera through MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Tags: android, file, android-camera, android-camera-intent

When opening the camera with the `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent`.It saves a 0kb or blank file in the sd card despite not saving the image,even if i dont save the image or discard the image or just return back.**EDIT:: But it proper images are saved if i save the image**.Below is the code which i am working on :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.VideoView;


public class DocsAdd extends Activity 
{

    private static final int ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B = 1;


    private static final String BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY = "viewbitmap";
    private static final String IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY = "imageviewvisibility";
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private Bitmap mImageBitmap;



    private String mCurrentPhotoPath;

    private static final String JPEG_FILE_PREFIX = "IMG_";
    private static final String JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX = ".jpg";


    private File getAlbumDir() 
    {

        Log.i("inside ", "docs add");
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();          
        File filenamedemo = new File(path + "/AutoistDiary/ImageFolder/");

        String name=String.valueOf(filenamedemo);
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) 
        {

            if (name != null) 
            {
                if (! filenamedemo.mkdirs()) 
                {
                    if (! filenamedemo.exists())
                    {
                        Log.d("CameraSample", "failed to create directory");
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }

        } else {

        }

        return filenamedemo;
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = JPEG_FILE_PREFIX + timeStamp + "_";
        File albumF = getAlbumDir();
        File imageF = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX, albumF);
        return imageF;
    }

    private File setUpPhotoFile() throws IOException {

        File f = createImageFile();
        mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();

        return f;
    }


    private void galleryAddPic() {
            Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE");
            File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
            mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
            this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);


            File f = null;

            try {
                f = setUpPhotoFile();
                mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                f = null;
                mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
            }

        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,0);
    }



private void handleBigCameraPhoto() 
    {

        if (mCurrentPhotoPath != null) 
        {
            //setPic();
            galleryAddPic();
            mCurrentPhotoPath = null;

            Intent viewint=new Intent(DocsAdd.this, DocsShow.class);        
            Log.i("calling ", "view activity");
            startActivity(viewint);
            finish();
        }

    }


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        dispatchTakePictureIntent();

        /*if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
            mAlbumStorageDirFactory = new FroyoAlbumDirFactory();
        } else {
            mAlbumStorageDirFactory = new BaseAlbumDirFactory();
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        handleBigCameraPhoto(); 
    }

    // Some lifecycle callbacks so that the image can survive orientation change
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putParcelable(BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY, mImageBitmap);

        outState.putBoolean(IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY, (mImageBitmap != null) );

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        mImageBitmap = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
        mImageView.setVisibility(
                savedInstanceState.getBoolean(IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY) ? 
                        ImageView.VISIBLE : ImageView.INVISIBLE
        );

    }

    /**
     * Indicates whether the specified action can be used as an intent. This
     * method queries the package manager for installed packages that can
     * respond to an intent with the specified action. If no suitable package is
     * found, this method returns false.
     * http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/can-i-use-this-intent.html
     *
     * @param context The application's environment.
     * @param action The Intent action to check for availability.
     *
     * @return True if an Intent with the specified action can be sent and
     *         responded to, false otherwise.
     */
    public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, String action) 
    {
        final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        List<ResolveInfo> list =packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        return list.size() > 0;
    }

     /** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
    private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {
       String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE",
             "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       int action = event.getAction();
       int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
       sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);
       if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
             || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
          sb.append("(pid ").append(
                action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
          sb.append(")");
       }
       sb.append("[");
       for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
          sb.append("#").append(i);
          sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
          sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
          sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
          if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
             sb.append(";");
       }
       sb.append("]");

    }


    /** Determine the space between the first two fingers */
    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
       float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
       float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
       return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    /** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */
    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
       float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
       float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
       point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }

    public void onCancel() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("on click", "discard image");
        Log.d("on click", "discard image hahahahahaaaaaa");
    }
}
```

Can anyone point out why a blank file is saved or what can be done regarding this issue.

Comment: Do u Add All permissions for Camera

Comment: @Arju yes i am giving all the required permission

Comment: @sankettt got solution?

Comment: @CapDroid yes i did got the solution will update the answer soon..!

Comment: @sankett please post your solution, I am also facing the same issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I recently had the same problem after copy-pasting the same code that OP used.

You are creating the file for the photo before the ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent is started, in the method `createImageFile()`. You need to handle the situation where the picture is not taken properly and dispose of that file you created. For example:

```
    if(requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //pic taken properly
        } else {
            //pic was not taken properly, deal with the empty file you created
        }
    }
```